# Understanding Models with multiple meshes

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

So I'm trying to design a model class for my OpenGL project, but I'm trying to figure out how I data should be stored generically to be able to render an entire model.

For example, a car model. The car would consist of three meshes: the body, wheel, and axle. I want the wheels to rotate with the axles and the axles to follow the body around.

My current class setup is as follows:

```
struct Vertex {
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 normal;
    glm::vec2 texCoord;
};

struct Texture {
    unsigned int id;
    std::string type;
};


class Mesh
{
public:
    Mesh();
    Mesh(std::vector<Vertex> pVerticies, std::vector<unsigned int> pIndicies, std::vector<Texture> pTextures);
    ~Mesh();

private:
    std::vector<Vertex> verticies;
    std::vector<unsigned int> indicies;
    std::vector<Texture> textures;
};
```

And the model class

```
class Model
{
public:
    Model();
    ~Model();

private:
    std::vector<Mesh> meshes;
    unsigned int shaderID;
};
```

The model class is not fleshed out at all since I don't know how to store the relationship data.

Comment: You need to store also the **type** of the mesh (body, wheel, axle). Each type may have a different behaviour Then for a given situation use the "angle of rotation for this wheel" or some info alike, proper for each type.

Comment: Doesn't that then become way more complex when the project gets larger? I can't possibly have a case for every possibility in a generic model class.

Comment: One common way to represent such mesh hierarchies is a scene graph.